# jQuery not seeing checbox and radio

Tags: jquery, pug

```
  $('form input, textarea').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).prop('tagName'))
  })
```

I don't know why but code above is not working for checkbox and radio. I get inputs of type text or number or email but no checkbox or radio in spite of the fact the are input's also. Anyone?

edit - example code. jQuery sees `teamSize` and `projectStack`, but not `projectStage`:

```
<form @submit.prevent="validateForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="whyWorkOnProject">Why would someone want to work on the project?</label>
    <textarea name="whyWorkOnProject" v-model="whyWorkOnProject" rows="3" type="text" placeholder="Please describe why would someone want to work on the project" class="form-control"></textarea><small class="invalid-feedback help-block"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="teamSize">How many people work on project?</label>
    <input name="teamSize" type="number" placeholder="Enter number" v-model="teamSize" class="form-control"/><small class="invalid-feedback help-block"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="projectStage">What stage is project at?</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="projectStage" v-model="projectStage" value="greenfield" checked="checked" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">greenfield</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="projectStage" v-model="projectStage" value="ongoing-development" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">ongoing development</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="radio" name="projectStage" v-model="projectStage" value="maintenance" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">maintenance</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="projectStack">What is the project techstack?</label>
    <textarea name="projectStack" v-model="projectStack" rows="3" type="text" placeholder="Please describe technology stack" class="form-control"></textarea><small class="invalid-feedback help-block"></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="projectMethodology">What stage is project at?</label>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" v-model="projectMethodology" value="issue tracking tool" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">issue tracking tool</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" v-model="projectMethodology" value="knowledge repository" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">knowledge repository</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" v-model="projectMethodology" value="code reviews" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">code reviews</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" v-model="projectMethodology" value="pair programming" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">pair programming</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" v-model="projectMethodology" value="unit testing" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">unit testing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" v-model="projectMethodology" value="integration testing" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">integration testing</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" v-model="projectMethodology" value="Agile/Lean/Waterfall" class="form-check-input"/>
      <label class="form-check-label">Agile/Lean/Waterfall</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you need to share your html also to figure out a solution, most probably your checkboxes are not inside the form..

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add this - updated my question (it's written with pug)

Comment: FYI When I convert your pug into html via https://pughtml.com/ the `<form>` element is closed before the content.

Comment: Okay, I converted from pug to html just to make sure it's easier to read

Comment: is this pug related (never used it)? Seems to work fine as just html https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/136063/

Comment: Nope, someone else brought this tag in, but the fact is your snippet works - don't know why. Taking a dive into it

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an indentation issue, make sure that your checkboxes are indented correctly like the other inputs you can select with jquery.

Comment: that html seems to work fine, have a look here https://jsfiddle.net/wd1q079z/3/ and check the console output

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like it was dumb error of mine. Console concatenated input that are following each other and just haven't seen number on the left of it... Thanks for your patience. I think we can delete this question.